# How can I modify this regex to include \ when it exists

Tags: regex

http://regexr.com/3b94f

Check out my regexr. I need it to handle this one edge case to match what's happening with the others. The capture group can contain the \ characters before the ending quotation marks but bonus points if it removes them

Comment: It would be better if you include, besides the regexr link, the details of your problem in the text of your question, like the regex expression, sample text and expected results. That way, people searching in the future can find the information more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modifications to your regex. Try this one here:
http://regexr.com/3b94i